# How to list, present created objects on my jupyter notebook IDE

Tags: python, directory, jupyter-notebook, space-complexity, del

I have created a lot of object names, more than 500 objects.

well, my question here is: How do i see the objects created or how do i clear the space, so that i can save few space on directory.

OR

it will not affect my storage at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on [Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61556182/12818901) :

```
## create some variables/objects
a = 5
b = 10
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100, size=(4,2)), columns=list('AB'))
print(a,b,'\n', df)

## check
%who
# >>> a b df np pd


#%%% Delete all

## clear with prompt
%reset
## clear without confirmation prompt
%reset -f

# check
%who


#%%% Delete specific

#%%%%  %reset_selective <regular_expression>

## clear with prompt
%reset_selective df

## clear without prompt
%reset_selective -f df

# multiple
%reset_selective -f [a,b]
# %reset_selective -f a,b  << doesn't work

## check
%who



#%%%% del
# clears without prompt

del a
## multiple
del [a,b]
# or
del a,b

## check
%who
```

Answer (score 2):

1) For inspecting globally created objects I suggest the [variable inspector extension](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/varInspector/README.html). For installing [refer to the docs](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).

2) For cleaning the global variables you could run:

- `%reset` with prompts
- `%reset -f` without prompts
- `%reset_selective <regular_expression>` to clean selected variables that match the regular expression

More about [%reset](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-reset) and [%reset_selective](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-reset_selective)